# Does this code-block from Scala documentation make sense?

Tags: scala

This example is from https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/ControlThrowable.html:

```
import scala.util.control.ControlThrowable

try {
  // Body might throw arbitrarily
} catch {
  case c: ControlThrowable => throw c // propagate
  case t: Exception        => log(t)  // log and suppress
}
```

I understand why `Throwable` must not be caught, but in this example we could remove `case c: ControlThrowable => throw c // propagate` without any issues as the next case catches `Exception`, so `ControlThrowable`s will not be caught anyway. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Catching a throwable is considered bad practice in Scala. `ControlThrowable` is meant to be used in rare cases that the programmer has a `Throwable` that is intended for flow control. See [here](http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2010/09/20/catching-throwable-in-scala/)

Comment: Like I said, I _understand_ that catching `Throwable` is bad practice. That is explained in the link I sent too. But removing that line doesn't mean all `Throwable`s will be caught -- `Exception` is a subtype of `Throwable`.

Comment: @jrook `ControlThrowable` is used by Scala internally. It's almost never used by the programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to extend on Brian McCutchon answer. I believe there are several different (highly-philosophical) aspects worth considering.

One might argue that the reason you can inherit directly from `Throwable` is that because Java type system does not have a way to prohibit such extension, and that the `Throwable`s hierarchy was not designed to add more classes that are not sub-classes of `Error` or `Exception`. This is probably the reason why things like [`NonLocalReturnException`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/69e1ddb55a7f122715dbed337de73f595ae00dc3/src/library/scala/runtime/NonLocalReturnException.scala) or [`BreakException`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/69e1ddb55a7f122715dbed337de73f595ae00dc3/src/library/scala/util/control/Breaks.scala) were originally subtypes of `RuntimeException` rather than directly `Throwable`.

Another point is that when introducing such a marker, it had to be a `trait`. And again in Scala type system there is no way to enforce that classes that will mix in this trait should be *not* a subclasses of `Exception`.

Together those two facts mean that there might be and actually historically there were subclasses of `ControlThrowable` (then `ControlException`) that are subclasses of `Exception`. Keeping this in mind, it becomes clear that the sets of types caught be those two cases were not disjoint by design. Yes, almost a year later after the [introduction of `ControlException`](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/69e1ddb55a7f122715dbed337de73f595ae00dc3) it was [changed to be `ControlThrowable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/34b8e8fcbbb1b11ce81bf69b730abcb78b6699ec#diff-6c6acf7d005456a7fa580625a29aef49) but at that point there was not way to enforce all the other (custom) subclasses to make the same switch.

One more philosophical point about such code as in this example is that even if there are no sub-types of `ControlThrowable` in the program that are subtypes of `Exception` and the first case really does not affect the behavior of the second case (as it is most probably the case today), it still shows that the developer has thought about this particular detail. And obviously the code should be written for other humans as much as for computers.

As the last note, today you should probably use [`NonFatal`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html), which includes test for `ControlThrowable`, instead.

Comment: Is there any scenario where I would mix in `ControlThrowable`? I thought that trait was purely for Scala's internal use.

Comment: @lfk, it is for internal usage but there is no way to prohibit you from using it. I can imagine some scenarios when an advanced (and macro-based) library might want to have some non-local control flow facilities and used a similar technique. One area of such libraries might be some kind of async support such as [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/scala-async) (AFAIK it doesn't use `ControlThrowable` but I can imagine something similar that might use it) another similar area is some kind of cooperative concurrency aka co-routines support.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't useless.

Consider this:

```
class FooException extends Exception with ControlThrowable
```

This would be caught by the first block and rethrown, never reaching the second block. It's probably a bad idea to write exceptions like that, but, back when ControlThrowable was first introduced (then called ControlException), this was [not uncommon in the standard library](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/69e1ddb55a7f122715dbed337de73f595ae00dc3).

Comment: So should I expect any `Exception`s that are `ControlThrowable` as well in 2.11+ or is that a thing of the past?

Answer (score 0):

The code originally is written as [`ControlThrowable`'s source code comment](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/util/control/ControlThrowable.scala).

Just like you mentioned, You can remove the line unless you have a possibility producing a custom Exception extending `ControlThrowable` though, This code was meant to tell you that Do not catch and supress `ControlThrowable`.
If the code was

```
try {
  // Body might throw arbitrarily
} catch {
  case c: ControlThrowable => throw c // propagate
  case t: Throwable        => log(t)  // log and suppress
}
```

then, it might be easier to understand what the code is trying to tell.

FYI, scala 2.12 has a bug that there is no way to suppress `ControlThrowable`.

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks
import scala.util.control.ControlThrowable
val b = new Breaks

b.breakable {
  try {
    for (num <- 1 to 10) {
      num match {
        case 5 => throw new RuntimeException("5")
        case 6 => b.break
        case x => println(x)
      }
    }
  } catch {
     case c: Throwable => println(c)
  }
}
```

This code should print numbers up to 10 because `b.break` produces `ControlThrowable` and it gets suppressed before `b.breakable` gets it. But because of the bug, It prints up to 5.

So using scala 2.12, ControlThrowable will be propagated anyway. It doesn't require the line `case c: ControlThrowable => throw c // propagate`. But for migration purpose, You shouldn't write so.

In fact, this bug will be fixed in 2.13.x https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7413

Comment: Yep, catching `ControlThrowable` before `Throwable` makes perfect sense to me and in fact I have that in my code.